# REST api predict to Tensorflow serving for BoostedTreesClassifier returns error

Tags: tensorflow, prediction, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am attempting to make predictions by serving the saved BoostedTreesClassifier model through Tensorflow's Restful API as directed in the following link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#model_metadata_api.

In the following code, I train my boostedTreesClassifier:

```
def trainAndEvalBoostedTrees(train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y, selected_col_objs):
    def make_inmemory_train_input_fn(train_x, train_y):
        def input_fn():
            return dict(train_x), train_y

        return input_fn

    def make_input_fn(test_x, train_y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
        def input_fn():
            dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(test_x), train_y))
            if shuffle:
                dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(train_x))
            # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
            dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
            # In memory training doesn't use batching.
            dataset = dataset.batch(len(train_x))
            return dataset

        return input_fn

    train_input_fn = make_inmemory_train_input_fn(train_x, train_y)
    eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(test_x, test_y, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1)
    est = tf.contrib.estimator.boosted_trees_classifier_train_in_memory(
        train_input_fn,
        selected_col_objs)
    return est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)['accuracy'], est
```

This is how I save the model:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    features = {}
    for key in train_x.keys():
        dt = train_x[key].dtype
        features[key] = tf.placeholder(dtype=dt, name=key, shape=[1, 1])
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, features)
    boostedTreesLoc = boostedTreesClassifier.export_savedmodel(boosted_trees_save_path, serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

The post request, requests.post("http://localhost:8501/v1/models/boostedTrees:predict", json=data) reached the saved BoostedTreesClassifier, which was being served on a Docker container, but returned the following error:

b'{ "error": "axis = 1 not in [-1, 1)\n\t [[{{node boosted_trees/unstack_1}}]]" }'
{'error': 'axis = 1 not in [-1, 1)\n\t [[{{node boosted_trees/unstack_1}}]]'}.

I confirmed that the input data was formatted properly, but I am not sure how to debug or fix this problem. I would appreciate any suggestions.